# Restrict account from deleting folder in S3 but allow read/write into that folder

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to allow users full access to subfolders, but not allow them to delete the subfolder. I have written this policy, but it doesn't work. It still lets the user delete the "inbound" and "outbound" folders.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListForAllowedBucket",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:HeadBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketVersions",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketxxxx"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowUserToListAllBuckets",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:HeadBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllUserFullAccessWithinStandardFolders",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketxxxx/marketing/inbound/*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketxxxx/marketing/outbound/*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyUserFromDeletingStandardFolders",
        "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketxxxx/marketing/inbound",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketxxxx/marketing/outbound"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Is it possible to do what I want ?

Comment: What do you mean by "not allow them to delete the subfolder"? Folders do not actually exist in Amazon S3. Rather, objects include their full path in the Key (filename). To delete a subfolder, they need to delete every object in the folder. So _WHY_ do you wish to prevent them from deleting folders if they are being given permission to delete objects in the folders?

Comment: I know "folders" as such don't exist in S3, I am using that term loosely to explain what I am trying to do here.

Comment: BTW,  that's how AWS refers to the key/path ->(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-folder.html).

I don't want them to be able to delete the 'inbound'  "folder" here for example (mybucketxxxx/marketing/inbound), because it's used by multiple users, however, they can put files there and be able to delete them after they have been processed.

Comment: The folder can only be "deleted" if there are no objects in the folder. And it doesn't matter if it is deleted because it will be recreated if an object gets created in that path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the last part of your policy to:

```
{
    "Sid": "DenyUserFromDeletingStandardFolders",
    "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteObject"
    ],
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketxxxx/marketing/inbound/",
        "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketxxxx/marketing/outbound/"
    ]
}
```

This is because an earlier policy grants `/*` which includes `/`, but this policy specifically denies `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate IAM role, for that Role give s3 all permissions except delete.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this. I was looking for a similar solution. Just for the reference of other guys like me. This policy helped me restrict a particular user from deleting objects inside a folder as well as the folder itself.

```
{
    "Sid": "DenyUserFromDeletingStandardFolders",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXX:user/XXXXXX"
    },
    "Action": "s3:DeleteObject",
    "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::XXXXXXX/folder*"
    ]
```